# First root login read issue

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I wanted to execute script which basically asks user a question and depending upon input from user configure values of custom application. The problem is that its getting executed but doesn't prompt user for input and takes default values.

I have called script from bashrc of root user as below

```
if [ -e /opt/services_vm/autoUpgrade.sh ];
then
  /opt/services_vm/autoUpgrade.sh
fi
```

Autoupgrade script looks as below

```
#!/bin/bash

    while true; do
            read -p "Do you want to enable automatic upgrade [Y|y - Yes] [N|n - No] [Yes] ?" yn
            case $yn in
                     [Yy] | "" ) sed -i "s#<autoupgrade-enabled>OFF<\/autoupgrade-enabled>#<autoupgrade-enabled>ON<\/autoupgrade-enabled>#g" /opt/avaya/SAL/gateway/SpiritAgent/config/agent/SPIRITAgent_1_0_PDComponentConfig.xml;
                                rm -rf /opt/services_vm/autoUpgrade.sh
                                exit;;
                     [Nn] ) rm -rf /opt/services_vm/autoUpgrade.sh
                            exit;;
                     * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
            esac
    done
```

The issue is that its not prompting user for input and first case statement is getting executed by default .I can see that in logs . Also root user has to changed pass on first attempt as per configuration I made. Its forcing user to change pass and executing below script but taking default input instead of prompting to user.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script as below, put it in .bashrc and it works as expected. It prompt and the answer is taken into action ( it echo the correct word). Try it first. I feel the issue is not from your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        read -p "Do you want to enable automatic upgrade [Y|y - Yes] [N|n - No] [Yes] ?" yn
        case $yn in
                 [Yy] | "" ) echo YES;
                            exit;;
                 [Nn] )  echo NO; 
                        exit;;
                 * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
        esac
done
```

Comment: It works if i put it manually. But i want it to be executed on first root login only  ,coded self delete statement in script for this reason . its VM wherein I am creating image for cents OS and deploying it on machine.I have configured root user to change password on first login  and was expecting scripts should get executed after that.

Comment: since call to script is from .bashrc file i was expecting script to be executed once root logs in . Not sure at what time script getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is self deleting script , it was getting deleted before first root login . Not sure how root .bashrc is getting executed , may be sourced by other scripts . And I was in wrong impression that its not getting called on first root login.
Thanks Kambiz for u r time.